# ajax request never enters deferred object done()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

i have the following requests:

```
var req1 = $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                URL: "http://...",
                dataType : "xml"
            });

        req1.done(function (resp1) {
            alert(" 1: " + resp1);
            // This will execute after the first request is done
            var req2 = $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                URL: "http://...",
                dataType: "jsonp"
            });

            $.when(req2).done(function (resp2) {
                alert(" 2: " + resp2);
                // when other three request are done
            });
        });
```

The problem i have with this is that it never enters neither the .done() and prints resp1 and neither does the when and prints resp2. Why?

I am using jquery 1.10.2

***EDIT:***
resp1 is returning the html of the page itself. If i make a normal ajax request it would work. but like this it is not. Why?

Comment: Most likely you have a parse error. Change `dataType` to `text` and confirm the structure of the data being returned first.

Comment: you are right i dont get it. if i do a normal ajax request the response comes in xml format as it should if i do it this way i am getting returned the page itself. The html. why?

Comment: Probably `done` is not called because the deferred is rejected. Also add an error handler, and check your console for exceptions.

Comment: since i changed it to dataType: text its returning something and printing, but it is printing the page itself and not the xml it should return.

Comment: Then either you request the wrong url, forget to send data or credentials, or your server is misconfigured. Edit: Uh, of course you do, `URL` needs to be `url`

Comment: thx a lot. if u make an answer ill give u accept.

Comment: FYI: You don't need `$.when(req2).done`. You're needlessly wrapping an existing promise in another promise. Just use `req2.done`.

Comment: If you set the content-type header, that should resolve your issue. In `PHP` you would use the line: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Answer (score 0):

You want the set the `Content-type` header and your issue would be resolved. In `PHP` your would use the line:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```